# how i can do if between two dynamic variable in mediator script esb wso2

Tags: javascript, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I have this if condition  but does not work if the value is static,when I annee2 and annee1 static for example <2023 and >=2019 it works :
here is my code:

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[var table = [
{"TABLE_NAME":"20220917"},
{"TABLE_NAME":"20221018"},
{"TABLE_NAME":"20221211"},
{"TABLE_NAME":"20230417"}
]; 
var date2 ="20221211";
var date1 ="20191018";
var annee1=date1.substr(0, 4);
var annee2=date2.substr(0, 4);
for (var i=0; i<table.length;i++){
if(parseInt(table[i].TABLE_NAME.substr(0, 4))<parseInt(annee2) && (parseInt(table[i].TABLE_NAME.substr(0, 4))>=parseInt(annee1))){
str = str +" select * from "+"`"+table[i].TABLE_NAME+"`"+" " +union + "";
}}]]></script>
```

I get as error: Query was empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the given example, the value getting set to `annee2` is `2022` since the `date2` is set to `20221211`. But your Table list doesn't have dates before `2022`. Hence in the given example the `if` condition is never true.

Comment: yes it works thank you I add <= if not please I have a question when I modify var table by get property non static it does not work: <property expression="json-eval($.tablesname.table)" name="nomtable" scope="default" type="STRING"/>var table =mc.getProperty('nomtable');

Comment: @raniabensalem try getting the payload like `getPayloadJSON()` or try transforming the content to a JSON by using `JSON.parse(mc.getProperty('nomtable'))`. If it doesn't work please create a new SO question with all the information so we can take a better look.